# Android Monkey: How to recreate actions/interpret output

Tags: android, monkey

I'm really just wondering if there's any in-depth online documentation for the output or for how to recreate an error brought upon by the monkey tool.

I'm getting a log that looks like so...

```
:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(292.0574,106.04135)
:Sending Trackball (ACTION_MOVE): 0:(-1.0,-1.0)
:Sending Touch (ACTION_DOWN): 0:(247.0,37.0)
:Sending Touch (ACTION_UP): 0:(246.42902,42.985004)
...
// java.lang.NullPointerException
//  at my.package.name.onOptionsItemSelected(ViewActivity.java:541)
//  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
```

And I'm not sure where to begin in debugging.
For now, I'm just trying to think of possible scenarios that might create this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605361/android-monkey-stress-test-results-evaluation> please visit this link........I also have the same question.....

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce the test, use the `-s <seed>` option.

When you run monkey, it generates a code (seed) that you can use to repeat the same sequence of events when re-running it.

About the NullPointerException, we should take a look at the code.

Comment: Do you know if the seed will work if you run the monkey on a different device? Will it produce the same error? Like is it dependent on os version or exact same emulator